# target frame in iframe (target="_blank" not working)

Tags: iframe, frameset-iframe

I have a small problem. 
I'm using iframe to insert the banner (with link to the outside website).

```
<iframe src="http://wifi.tucado.com/ads/001.html" name="i001" target="_blank" frameset frameborder=0 id="i001" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The problem I have is when I click on the banner INSIDE the frame it opens a page INSIDE a frame and I want it to open it in new window (or at least in the parent one).
Is there any way to do it without js or jquery? 
If not, what should I do in jquery to make it working? I was trying to find an answer here, but found just very specific questions which don't face my problem directly. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can control the source file that is loaded inside the iFrame (`http://wifi.tucado.com/ads/001.html`), try adding a `target="_top"` or `target="_blank"` in the links there.

Comment: great work :) I didn't thought about this. works perfectly well. thanks