# hyper link with target="_blank" does not open in new tab

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have the below html code snipnet

`<a href="http://www.google.co.in" target="_blank" >Google</a>`

in a iframe.
Clicking on the a tag in ipad chrome opens in the same tab.
According to a tag parameters, it should open in new tab/window.

Am i missing something, Please let me know your thoughts about this.
Any reason why its blocked from opening in new tab in chrome

Comment: **[This answer might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12402682/2065039)**

Comment: Check if you have missing half tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [target frame in iframe (target="\_blank" not working)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402584/target-frame-in-iframe-target-blank-not-working)

Answer (score 6):

For Some reason it is not working so we can do this by another way

just remove the line and add this :-

```
<a onclick="window.open ('http://www.google.com', ''); return false" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

Comment: May i know what is the reason? is it a bug in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `href` and force opening the link in a new tab with:

```html
<a href="http://www.google.co.in" onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;">Google</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `_top` instead of `_blank`:

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.in" target="_top" >Google</a>
```